# How to iterate through two vectors within a loop

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, vector, stdvector

I am trying to access several elements between two different vectors within a for loop. Visual studio gives me the following warning C26451;

Arithmetic overflow: Using operator '+' on a 4 byte value and then casting the result to a 8 byte value. Cast the value to the wider type before calling operator '+' to avoid overflow (io.2).

I have tried casting a variety of data types but understand that I should be using iterators to move through a vector in a loop, **however as I am using two vectors within the loop and several elements for each vector at once I cannot find a way to implement this correctly.** 
Here are two different functions I am having the same issue in;

First function;

```
Mat drawRails(Mat draw, vector<Point>lLines, vector<Point>rLines) {
//draw rails to the input image
    for (int j = 0; j < lLines.size() - 1; j++) {
        //draw rails - accessing point j and next point to correctly define the line
        line(draw, lLines[j], lLines[j + 1], Scalar(255, 255, 255), 4);
        line(draw, rLines[j], rLines[j + 1], Scalar(255, 255, 255), 4);
    }
    return draw;
}
```

Second function;

```
Mat drawHazardLines(Mat draw, vector<Point>lLines, vector<Point>rLines, int frameNum) {
//draw hazard lines to track
    for (int j = 0; j < lLines.size() - 1; j++) {
        //draw outwards moving rail lines - divide rail width by ten and multiply by modulo 10 of frame to achieve motion
        int railDistNext = (rLines[j + 1].x - lLines[j + 1].x) / 10 * (frameNum % 10) + 2;
        int railDist = (rLines[j].x - lLines[j].x) / 10 * (frameNum % 10) + 2;


        Point Low, High;
        Low = Point(lLines[j].x - railDist, lLines[j].y);
        High = Point(lLines[j + 1].x - railDistNext, lLines[j + 1].y);
        line(draw, Low, High, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 4);

        Low = Point(rLines[j].x + railDist, rLines[j].y);
        High = Point(rLines[j + 1].x + railDistNext, rLines[j + 1].y);
        line(draw, Low, High, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 4);
    }
    return draw;
}
```

The code works fine however produces the above mentioned errors which I would like to resolve

Comment: Unrelated, neither of those vectors appear to actually be modified by either function. Why you're not passing them by const-reference is a mystery. Stress-testing the copy-ctor ? An fyi, `int j = 0; j < lLines.size() - 1` is a terrible idea. You do *not* want that calculation if that input vector is actually empty; the results will be most unpleasant. Use iterators.

Comment: The error/warning about arithmetic overflow has nothing to do with iterating over two vectors in a loop.   Try narrowing down which of the two questions you've asked that you actually want help with.    If you want help with both, ask separate questions.    Combining them as you have - along with not providing a [mcve] - reduces the chances of getting any useful advice.

Answer (score 2):

The error means that there is conversion from `long` to `int`.
From the code you provided it's hard to tell where the error is, but I would suggest changing `int` to `long` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(auto lIter = lLines.begin(), rIter = rLines.begin(); liter != lLines.end(); ++lIter, ++rIter)
{
   ... 
}
```

You need to ensure rLines has at least as many items as lLines, of course...